# RiCal add_attendee issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using RiCal gem to create calendar event in my ROR project. The issue i have  is when i add attendee it adds the attendee as .

ATTENDEE:mailto:sanjay.swain@in.ibm.com
ATTENDEE:mailto:sanjayswa@gmail.com

But I want ATTENDEE as

ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=
 TRUE;CN=sanjay.swain@in.ibm.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:sanjay.swain@in.ibm.c
 om

with ROLE, PARTSTAT etc.. Is there a way to get this result using RiCal gem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. Here is what I have done:

```
options = {'CUTYPE' => 'INDIVIDUAL','RSVP' => 'TRUE','ROLE' => 'REQ-PARTICIPANT','PARTSTAT' => 'NEEDS-ACTION','X-NUM-GUESTS' => '0'}
attendee_property = RiCal::PropertyValue::CalAddress.new(nil, :value => "mailto:"+attend, :params => options)
event.attendee_property = attendee_property
```

Comment: I found the solution by myself

Comment: suggest event.attendee_property << attendee_property to support many attendees